# Razor, shortest conditional block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I frequently use code like:

```
<p @if(Model.Sth)
{
    ?:style="display: none;"
}>Some text</p>
```

Many template engines have special markers for conditional blocks, for example in Mustache you can write:

```
<p {{#Model.Sth}}style="display: none;"{{/Model.Sth}}>Some text</p>
```

Can my Razor code can be written in shorter form?

Answer (score 3):

In Razor you can embed expressions inside parenthesis to execute them inline. If your conditional can be written using the ternary operator, then you can do something like this:

```
@(this.Model.Sth ? "style='display:none;'" : string.Empty)
```

The trick is getting Razor to emit the resulting string correctly back into your HTML. You could use `HtmlHelper` to do it, but it gets messy enough that the long-form conditional is much cleaner.

In the specific case of an attribute, however, there's a special feature of Razor, as of MVC4, that will help. If you specify an attribute using an expression that evaluates to `null`, MVC won't emit the attribute at all, so you can do:

```
<p style="@(this.Model.Sth ? "display:none;" : null)">Some Text</p>
```

(Note that `null` and `string.Empty` are different in this case: Razor will emit `style=""` if your expression evaluates to empty string.)